# Trying to visualize the concept of qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

**Background**

Complete newbie, never taken a physics course.

**Question**

I'm trying to visualize the concept of [qubits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit).
Qubits can achieve a mixed state, called a "superposition" where they are both $1$ and $0$ at the same time.

I originally thought of qubits as being like a door that is both open and closed simultaneously.

Suppose sets $A,C$ represents $0$'s and $B,D$ represents $1$'s.
These sets have rules:

- $F = A \cap B$. (superposition state represented by the shaded area)
- $G = C \cap D$. (superposition state represented by the shaded area)
- $H = F$. (represents the new superposition state)
- $I = G$. (represents the new superposition state)
- $J = H \cap I$. (superposition of superposition states represented by the shaded area)

Is that a good way to view qubits?
Can a superposition of superpositions exist ad infinitum?

[image: qubits]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to visualize or think about Qubits, if indeed you are actually interested in understanding them; the hand-wavy idea of superposition as a mixture is often used to give a quick overview to people who want the cliffnotes version of the cliffnotes version of Quantum Computing.

A much better way to visualize Qubits is with the use of the Bloch Sphere, this can help in understanding the relationships between observable eigenstates, pure states(super position states), and mixed states. I won't go into too much detail since there are many posts on Physics SE, and many more on Quantum Computing SE that discuss the Bloch Sphere and what can be drawn from it, but let me just show where your analogy/visualization fails.

We define our computational basis as $|0 \rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$, a Qubit $| \psi \rangle$ can be in a superposition of these states, meaning $|\psi \rangle = \alpha|0 \rangle+ \beta|1 \rangle$, where $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 =1$ and each coefficent's magnitude square represents the probability of finding the state in the corresponding $0$ or $1$ state.

Now notice with this definition of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we can have $|\psi_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|0 \rangle+ \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|1 \rangle$, or $|\psi_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|0 \rangle- \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|1 \rangle$. Although you may be looking at those two states and thinking that the probabilities for measuring $0$ and $1$ are identical and so therefore the states are also identical, you would be incorrect. These states are actually orthogonal to each other and span a new basis which we commonly denote as $|+ \rangle$ and $|- \rangle$. They are eigenstates of a different observable. And so just because they are probabilistically identical as it relates to measurements made in the computational basis does not mean that the states themselves are identical.

Quantum Computing operates under a different physical paradigm than classical computing, and probabilities are not the end all and be all of this paradigm, but a consequence of it. As a result thinking about Quantum Computing or Qubits as merely objects of a probabilistic nature misses the essence, power and beauty of QC.